# Mysql inner join query showing wrong result

Tags: mysql, database, join, inner-join

I have two tables in MySQL

[image]

and

[image]

I want to show Categories in place of Cid in first table. I'm using following query:

```
SELECT id,categorymass.Cid,video.Name 
from video inner join categorymass on video.Cid = categorymass.Cid
```

What is problem in my inner join

Comment: WHAT result exactly is shown? You only tell us, it is "wrong", but not, what is wrong

Comment: Try `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `INNER` if you want to keep all your categories in case not all of them exist in `Video` table.

Comment: @MilenPavlov It is showing only Cid value like 1,2,3 but I want it to show from second table

Comment: in both table which is video table

Comment: @notulysses no I don't want so I just wanted to show category in place of Cid from my inner join query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well You are not selecting category...

```
SELECT id,categorymass.Cid, categorymass.Category,video.Name 
    from video inner join categorymass on video.Cid = categorymass.Cid
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
SELECT t2.`Cid`, t2.`Category`,t1.`Name` 
    from video t1 JOIN categorymass t2 on t1.`Cid` = t2.`Cid`
```